# Like in Where-Object doesn't work in PowerShell 2

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a piece of script to do some stuff on VMs. Here it is:

```
$powered = Get-VM VM-TEST4-* | Where-Object { $_.PowerState -eq 'PoweredOn'
ForEach-Object -InputObject $powered { Shutdown-VMGuest -VM $_ }

# taking snapshots etc etc

# BELOW FAILS
# start up machines in order

Where-Object -Like -Property Name -InputObject $powered -Value "VM-TEST4-DB*" | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -ne $null) { Start-VM -VM $_ } }
sleep -Seconds 180
Where-Object -Like -Property Name -InputObject $powered -Value "VM-TEST4-AUX*" | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -ne $null) { Start-VM -VM $_ } }
sleep -Seconds 180
Where-Object -Like -Property Name -InputObject $powered -Value "VM-TEST4-WEB*" | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -ne $null) { Start-VM -VM $_ } }
sleep -Seconds 180
```

My problem with this code is that nothing gets started and I only wait. Now the idea behind it was to filter out correct server type so that DB starts earlier than AUX and WEB while `$_ -ne $null` check protects me if `Where-Object` returns no results (we have an enviroment with no AUX servers).

Any idea how to make it work properly?

Comment: `-Like` was introduced in 3.0 as per [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715.aspx)

Comment: any alternatives? and then I don't know why it doesn't error out. It just does nothing

Comment: `$powered | Where-Object{Name -like "VM-TEST4-WEB*"}`. Im sure `-match` would work as well without the astericks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplified where-object syntax (including the -like switch parameter) was introduced in 3.0.  The -like operator works fine in the standard where-object syntax.  You want something like this:

```
Where-Object {$_.Name -like "VM-TEST4-WEB*"}
```

EDIT:
  The -Like parameter for where-object (which looks like an operator in the simplified syntax) was added in 3.0.  The -Like operator which does string comparisons has been in PowerShell since 1.0